# How do you make the best DPS warrior?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

How should I go about building a great DPS warrior?  I am playing the default role of a Noble Warrior. Alister is my tank, and I'm using the build and tips from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18579/how-to-make-alistair-the-best-sword-and-board-tank/18583#18583). In the end my main group will be a warrior tank, warrior dps, mage healer, and mage/rogue dps.

What suggestions do you have for the following:

- Specializations *(currently only missing Champion)*
- Attribute
- Skills
- Talent
- Tactics
- Equipment

*Note: This is my first play though. Playing with Dragon Age: Origins - Ultimate Edition.*

Comment: Are the answers below relevant to DOA2? Or has the system changed that much?

Comment: Isn't this the [same question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18579/how-do-i-make-alistair-the-best-sword-and-board-tank/) from which you are using tips?

Comment: No... Because many don't consider the sword-and-board warrior the best DPS warrior.

Answer (score 3):

Also depends on what kind of DPS you want (sustained vs burst). Burst is way better to kill casters, as they usually got low armor/HP: For that you'll want a 2handed weapon (axe, you don't need the armor penetration of clubs, and the extra damage), and you can send those dammed mage flying in pieces.

For sustained dps, dual wield is better (fun fact: Dual wielding as a rogue is way funnier, due to backstabs etc). You'll want at least one club for the arpen.

Overwall, sustained DPS is better damage than Burst, and easier to play, as it don't rely so much on active skills. However, 2Handers are extremely good soloers, almost guaranteed to win any one-on-one.

I'd go berserker + Templar (templar sucks, I know, but it's awesome for killing casters - and c'mon, casters are the only threat you face), use a 2hander stacking crit and attack speed.

Comment: @mxmissile DOA only, they changed the combat a LOT in DOA2 - No more different attack speeds for weapons, for instance.

Comment: You'll need to put your comment response to mxmissile on the question rather than your answer if you want the system to "ping" him with his name. Since he hasn't left a comment on this answer, he's not considered "participating" in this conversation.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes Ah ok, thank you ^^ upvote for you xD

Answer (score 1):

I saw some really advanced stuff on the wiki some time ago, it really depends on whether you are playing DAO or DAA. DAO you just whore attackspeed and make sure not to go over the limit which will reset your aspd. Flurry, dual striking, haste, and that sustainable that drops your attackspeed by 5~10% will maximize DPS.

For DAA, you need to get spirit damage increasing gear and get the spirit warrior spec